# jQueryMobile viewport not working in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, viewport

I'm testing jQueryMobile in WindowsPhone and the viewport isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a workaround on [this page](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/problem-with-virtual-viewport-size-on-windows-phone-7).

```
<!--[if IE 7]><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /><![endif]-->
```